# mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql

```
    3717    8   2012-03-30 16:34:17
    3718    10  2012-03-30 16:34:22
    3719    9   2012-03-30 16:34:27
    3720    6   2012-03-30 16:34:32
    3721    7   2012-03-30 16:34:37
        3722    8   2012-03-30 16:34:42
    3723    10  2012-03-30 16:34:47
    3724    5   2012-03-30 16:34:50
```

i have this mysql table and  iwanted to select the last 10 records i this is the code i have

```
SELECT * FROM mach_1 ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 10
```

this is what i get

```
2012-03-30 16:34:50
2012-03-30 16:34:47
2012-03-30 16:34:42
2012-03-30 16:34:37
2012-03-30 16:34:32
2012-03-30 16:34:27
2012-03-30 16:34:22
2012-03-30 16:34:17
2012-03-30 16:34:10
2012-03-30 16:34:05
```

the question is how can i reverse this

Comment: learn everything here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html   but change desc to asc

Comment: to make it simple :::: if we have a table with 1,2,3,4,5,6 if we select * from table order by id  desc limit 3 we will get 6,5,4 how do i reverse the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select * from (select * from mach_1 order by id desc 
limit 10) as tbl order by tbl.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you won't get around a nested select:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mach_1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) AS t ORDER BY t.id ASC
```

This will first select the last 10 entries and afterwards sort them ascending like you want.